# The aim of this paper is to clarify that

Tags: infinitives, adjuncts

1. The aim of this paper is **to clarify** that uniform asymptotic stability is equivalent to exponential stability for the half-linear differential system.(https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-015-0494-7)
2. The purpose of this contribution is **to clarify** that such algorithms need proper calculation of the update direction in undermodeled situations.(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667015323521)

Does "to clarify" here mean "**in order to** clarify"? In other words, is "to clarify" a *purpose infinitive* in (1) and (2)?

Comment: Purpose infinitives are explained [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478296/for-subj-to-infinitive-to-indicate-purpose). But it strikes me that the word *clarify* needs a direct object. "...to clarify *the fact* that..." might be better; or "...to make it clear that...". Mightn't it be better to replace "clarify" with "prove", "show" or "demonstrate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The aim of this paper is* [*to clarify that uniform asymptotic stability*
> *is equivalent to exponential stability for the half-linear*
> *differential system*].

Yes:the bracketed infinitival clause is a purpose complement.

It’s intended as a subtype of ascriptive PC: it ascribes a purpose to the predicand (*the* *aim of this paper*).

The same analysis applies to your other example.

Comment: Thanks. So it is just a **complement** of the subject/noun phrase, and NOT a **purpose infinitive**. Am I right?

Comment: @Mr.X No: It's a complement of the verb "be" ("is").  It 's an infinitival clause functioning as a purpose complement. You can also call it a "purpose infinitival".